# Generators of a finite CW complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My question regards a simple application of Van Kampen's theorem. Suppose $X$ is a finite CW complex with a finite one-skeleton. I have to show that X is finitely generated. I know that this is just an easy application of Van Kampen's theorem, but I'm not completely sure about the argument.

Comment: You probably mean that $\pi_1X$ is finitely generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclusion of the 1-skeleton generates the fundamental group, i.e. $\pi_1X^1 \to \pi_1X$ is onto. Since the 1-skeleton is a finite graph its fundamental group is free on finitely many generators, hence also $\pi_1X$ is finitely generated.

Now for my first statement you either use cellular approximation, which would tell you that every map $S^1 \to X$ is homotopic to a map $S^1 \to X^1 \to X$, or you can use inductively Van Kampen. For the latter consider a small (suitably chosen) neighborhood of $X^1$ and the complement of $X^1$. This neighborhood deformation retracts to $X^1$, hence inherits the fundamental group. The complement is a bunch of open discs, i.e. homotopically trivial space. For each component of the complement the conditions for Van Kampen are satisfied. Now try to deduce the rest and write down the result.